# When do parents in Turkey typically introduce food to their babies, and what kind of foods do they typically start with?

Tags: weaning

My question is country/cultural based. When a Turkish baby starts on solids, what kind of foods do the parents introduce to the child? E.g. mashed banana, baby food, etc.. I need to know if there re different types of food the parents in Turkey give their children.

Comment: I have no reason to think that Turkish babies are in any way different than other babies. If you want localized answers, look for your country's health instutute recommendations. Perhaps you have a ministry of health which publishes such informaton.

Comment: You seem to be combining several questions here, each of which may already have answers in other questions posted here.  Baby developmental milestones do not, to my knowledge, change simply due to the nation in which they are born.  I'm going to put this on hold; please either clarify what you are looking for (you can use the **edit** link to modify your post), or search through the site for existing questions on food introduction and self-feeding.

Comment: there might be cultural differences in what you feed and when you feed, though. In the US they recommend starting with solids at 6 months, in Denmark at 4 months. In the US many start with rice cereal, in Denmark many with apples. I know in some developing nations they start with meat pre-chewed by moms. So the question might be better phrased as: 'At what age does Turkish doctors typically recommend introducing babies to solids, and what foods do they recommend?'

Comment: @Beofett when the Turkish child starts eating, what solid foods do the Turkish parents introduce? I need to know if the food the parents introduce is different to other country's.

Comment: @KellieCrosbie I've reopened the question, but it would help people to provide better answers if you could explain *why* you need to know this.  Are you visiting Turkey with your infant?  Hosting a Turkish family with an infant?  Something else?  Please feel free to edit more details into your question to provide some context.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that even in Turkey each parents are different and do it differently.

Answer (score 2):

We gave labneh, home made yoghourt, egg yolk, mashed apple, banana and pear when he was 6 months old.

Comment: Thank you. thanks for your anwser. you gave the infomation i need to know. thanks again.